# how to set test iteration variable in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Is test_iter variable in BVLC and Nvidia's caffe same as tensorflow's NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN in the cifar example code? If not, where can I set test_iter and test_interval (as used in Caffe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7718d2a052042d6ee1d821c979661371e217f0d7/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L34) constant represents the number of images in the [training set for CIFAR-10 training](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html).

In Caffe, `test_iter` is the number of evaluation iterations to perform. 
[TensorFlow's CIFAR-10 eval](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7718d2a052042d6ee1d821c979661371e217f0d7/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py) performs evaluation on the complete set of 10000 images, does not have a quantity analogous to `test_iter`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there something same as test_interval in caffe?

Comment: The way the CIFAR-10 example is configured, it's not easy to do that: the train and eval programs are separate. However, you could modify [`cifar10_train.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py) so that it calls [`cifar10_eval.eval_once()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7718d2a052042d6ee1d821c979661371e217f0d7/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py#L62) after every (e.g.) 500 iterations of training, to simulate Caffe's `test_interval`.